# Html Slurping in Groovy

Tags: java, groovy, web-scraping

I am trying to parse HTML that comes to me as a giant String. When I get to Line 13, `NodeChild page = it.parent()`

I am able to find the key that I am looking for, but the data comes to me like `This Is Value One In My KeyThis is Value Two in my KeyThis is Value Three In My Key` and so on. I see a recurring trend where the seperator between the two is always UppercaseUppercase (withoutSpaces).

I would like to put it into an `ArrayList` one way or another. Is there a method that I am missing [from the docs](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/util/XmlSlurper.html) that is able to automatically do this? Is there a better way to parse this together?

```
class htmlParsingStuff{

    private def slurper = new XmlSlurper(new Parser())

    private void slurpItUp(String rawHTMLString){
        ArrayList urlList = []
        def htmlParser = slurper.parseText(rawHTMLString)

        htmlParser.depthFirst().findAll() {
            //Loop through all of the HTML Tags to get to the key that I am looking for 
            //EDIT: I see that I am able to iterate through the parent object, I just need a way to figure out how to get into that object
            boolean trigger = it.text() == 'someKey'
            if (trigger){
                //I found the key that I am looking for
                NodeChild page = it.parent()
                page = page.replace('someKey', '')
                LazyMap row = ["page": page, "type": "Some Type"]
                urlList.add(row)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: okay I think I'm on to something, didn't realize that you could call `.parent`, `.children`, `.childNodes`'

Answer (score 3):

I can't provide you with working code since I don't know your specific html.

But: don't use `XmlSlurper` for parsing HTML, HTML is not well formed and therefor `XmlSlurper` is not the right tool for the job.

For HTML use a library like [JSoup](https://jsoup.org/). You will find it much easier to use especially if you have some JQuery knowledge. Since you didn't post your HTML snippet I made up my own example:

```groovy
@Grab(group='org.jsoup', module='jsoup', version='1.10.1')
import org.jsoup.Jsoup

def html = """
<html>
<body>
  <table>
    <tr><td>Key 1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Key 2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Key 3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Key 4</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Key 5</td></tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>"""

def doc = Jsoup.parse(html)
def elements = doc.select('td')
def result = elements.collect {it.text()}
// contains ['Key 1', 'Key 2', 'Key 3', 'Key 4', 'Key 5']
```

To manipulate the document you would use

```groovy
def doc = Jsoup.parse(html)
def elements = doc.select('td')
elements.each { oldElement ->
    def newElement = new Element(Tag.valueOf('td'), '')
    newElement.text('Another key')
    oldElement.replaceWith(newElement)
}
println doc.outerHtml()
```